# Setting up babel-plugin-styled-components + Typescript + create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app, styled-components

We are currently trying to integrate the `babel-plugin-styled-components` into our `typescript` and `create-react-app` based setup for a better debugging experience and we are having difficulties doing so.

We are reluctant to eject the app, which is why we are trying to set it up using `react-app-rewired` and we also managed to get our typescript code to compile using `react-app-rewire-typescript` along with `react-app-rewire-styled-components`.
For some reason however, the `displayName` is not applied, which makes me think the babel plugin is not applied.
We are using `"start": "react-app-rewired start"` as our dev server script and the `config-overrides.js` looks like this:

```
const rewireTypescript = require('react-app-rewire-typescript');
const rewireStyledComponents = require('react-app-rewire-styled-components');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    return rewireTypescript(rewireStyledComponents(config, env), env);
}
```

I have no idea what we are missing. Swapping the encapsulation of the `rewire...` functions also didn't help.

Does anyone here have experience with that or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have any update for this problem?

Comment: Austin Brunkhorst might have created a suitable solution as he was having the exact same problem. He created a separate version of the babel plugin called `babel-plugin-styled-components-typescript` which seems to be compatible with typescript. Unfortunately I can't verify the soluton since I'm on a different project without typescript at the moment. You'll have to try it yourself. Find the relevant discussion here:
https://spectrum.chat/thread/1cb6a569-f86a-4feb-a950-e4bf0d410050?m=MTUzNDE5ODc4NjgwOA==

Answer (score 2):

If you are using webpack, I found a solution that did not require using babel.

https://github.com/Igorbek/typescript-plugin-styled-components

To use it, you add a custom transform to your typescript loader with webpack:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
      options: {
        getCustomTransformers: () => ({ before: [styledComponentsTransformer] })
      }
    }
```

This solves the `displayName` not showing when using styled-components and typescript.

Comment: What if I use babel 7 to transform TS?

Comment: @coinhndp we have since moved to babel 7 for our TS transforming which has worked out great. It required some slight adjustments since Babel does not support all TS syntax (see the "Caveats" section here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/typescript-and-babel-7/). But by switching we get all the first class support of the babel styled component plugin and get to now use the same TS compiler in our app as well as our tests (Jest relies natively on babel). Would recommend the switch.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by add something like this in config-overrides.js using react-app-rewired:

```
const createStyledComponentsTransformer = require('typescript-plugin-styled-components').default;
const styledComponentsTransformer = createStyledComponentsTransformer();

module.exports = function override(config, env) {

const rule = config.module.rules.filter(l => l.oneOf)[0];
const tsLoader = rule.oneOf.filter(l => String(l.test) === String(/\.(ts|tsx)$/))[0];
tsLoader.use[0].options.getCustomTransformers = () => ({
before: [styledComponentsTransformer]
  });

return config;
}
```